# Char.IsSymbol("*") is false

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a password validation routine, and am surprised to find that VB does not consider '*' to be a symbol per the Char.IsSymbol() check.
Here is the output from the QuickWatch:

```
char.IsSymbol("*")  False   Boolean
```

The [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.CHAR.ISSYMBOL%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true) does not specify what characters are matched by IsSymbol, but does imply that standard mathematical symbols are included [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00k2wda1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Does anyone have any good ideas for matching all standard US special characters?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3373600/142637) answer.

Comment: well, VB doesn't handle char->int the way C# does. the numeric value of "*" is returned as -1.0, not the ASCII code.

Comment: You'll have to use the `Asc`-method to get the ASCII value of a string/char in Visual Basic.

Comment: the documentation says that the .IsSymbol(char) method is unicode based. is there a good way to force the char to be read as a unicode char? I'm wondering if the IsSymbol will work then.

Comment: *is there a good way to force the char to be read as a unicode char?*: I don't know what you mean. `string`s and `char`s are always unicode in .Net.

Comment: so you believe that the failure to match "*" is not an input problem on my part, but a bug in the framework itself? I am usually inclined to believe 'I'm using it wrong', but you are likely right.

Comment: Have you read my answer? It's explains what's going on and how you can solve your issue...

Comment: yeah, saw that. I won't be able to get back to that bit of code until this weekend, so was waiting until then to get back to y'all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Characters that are symbols in this context: `UnicodeCategory.MathSymbol`, `UnicodeCategory.CurrencySymbol`, `UnicodeCategory.ModifierSymbol` and `UnicodeCategory.OtherSymbol` from the `System.Globalization` namespace. These are the Unicode characters designated Sm, Sc, Sk and So, respectively. All other characters return `False`.

From the .Net source:

```
internal static bool CheckSymbol(UnicodeCategory uc)
{
    switch (uc)
    {
        case UnicodeCategory.MathSymbol:
        case UnicodeCategory.CurrencySymbol:
        case UnicodeCategory.ModifierSymbol:
        case UnicodeCategory.OtherSymbol:
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

or converted to VB.Net:

```
Friend Shared Function CheckSymbol(uc As UnicodeCategory) As Boolean
    Select Case uc
        Case UnicodeCategory.MathSymbol, UnicodeCategory.CurrencySymbol, UnicodeCategory.ModifierSymbol, UnicodeCategory.OtherSymbol
            Return True
        Case Else
            Return False
    End Select
End Function
```

`CheckSymbol` is called by `IsSymbol` with the Unicode category of the given char.

Since the `*` is in the category `OtherPunctuation` (you can check this with `char.GetUnicodeCategory()`), it is not considered a symbol, and the method *correctly* returns `False`.

To answer your question: use `char.GetUnicodeCategory()` to check which category the character falls in, and decide to include it or not in your own logic.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  I had a real hard time understanding RegEx and this solution made more sense to me ;)

Answer (score 7):

If you simply need to know that character is something else than digit or letter,
use just

```
!char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)
```

preferably with

```
&& !char.IsControl(c)
```

Comment: well, I need to make sure that there are at least one instance of each of the following: upper case alpha, lower case alpha, numeric, and special character. We do disallow certian characters however, including <>/|' etc, as a standard injection filter. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the compiler option "strict" of, because with

```
Char.IsSymbol("*")
```

I get a compiler error

```
BC30512: Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Char'.
```

To define a Character literal in VB.NET, you must add a c to the string, like this:

```
Char.IsSymbol("*"c)
```

Comment: `Char.IsSymbol("*"c)` also returns False.

Comment: well, definitely no compiler error or warning on the topic. we don;t use strict,

Comment: @FrankThomas **start using strict**.

Comment: @ckuhn203, as Neolisk pointed out strict has no impact on whether the method works or not (the issue has nothing to do with parameter conversion). Additionally my shop's standard does not allow me to switch to strict. Either way, compiler strictures like this, while very useful, don't address the issue in any meaningful way, as the problem is not string -> char conversion.

Comment: Thank the gods I don't work in your shop. Any standard that doesn't allow for using strict is a silly one.

Answer (score 0):

`IsPunctuation(x)` is what you are looking for.

This worked for me in C#:

```cs
string Password = "";
ConsoleKeyInfo key;

do
{
    key = Console.ReadKey(true);
    // Ignore any key out of range.
   if (char.IsPunctuation(key.KeyChar) ||char.IsLetterOrDigit(key.KeyChar) || char.IsSymbol(key.KeyChar))
    {
        // Append the character to the password.
        Password += key.KeyChar;
        Console.Write("*");
    }
    // Exit if Enter key is pressed.
} while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
```