# Char.IsSymbol('%') does not work

Tags: c#

According to MS documentation this should work, but it does not.

```
Char.IsSymbol('%')
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.issymbol(v=vs.110).aspx

`Char.GetUnicodeCategory('%') == OtherPunctuation` and so should **return** *true* from `IsSymbol`.

Comment: Note that you're using percentage `%`, while the docs specifically mention this symbol [`℅`](https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%E2%84%85).

Comment: No, OtherPunctuation and OtherSymbol are two different categories, `%` falls into Punctuation, not Symbol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Char.IsSymbol("\*") is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708304/char-issymbol-is-false)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the category of the percent symbol is `OtherPunctuation`, then it is not in one of the categories that the documentation says is a symbol (MathSymbol, CurrencySymbol, ModifierSymbol, and OtherSymbol).

Comment: Right, my mistake.

Comment: Someone should tell MS that '%' IS a Symbol and not a Punctuation

Answer (score 5):

You're using percentage `%` (U+0025), instead of the character that the docs actually mention, `℅` ([U+2105, "care of"](https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%E2%84%85). Turns out it's actually a tiny, unreadable "c/o", [as used on on letters](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/care_of)):

> Symbols in the Unicode standard are a loosely defined set of characters that include the following:
>
> - Currency symbols.
> - Letterlike symbols, which include a set of mathematical alphanumeric symbols as well as symbols such as ℅, №, and ™.

This symbol is classified as `OtherSymbol`:

```
Char.GetUnicodeCategory('℅') == OtherSymbol
Char.IsSymbol('℅') == true
```

The percentage character is just a normal punctuation character, and not a symbol:

```
Char.GetUnicodeCategory('%') == OtherPunctuation
Char.IsPunctuation('%') == true
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. The char displayed on the MSDN page looks like a percentage-sign, but it's actually higher unicode.

```
var z = '℅'; // 8453
var zz = '%'; // 37
var a = char.IsSymbol(z);
var aa = char.IsSymbol(zz);
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708304/char-issymbol-is-false):

Characters that are symbols in this context: `UnicodeCategory.MathSymbol`, `UnicodeCategory.CurrencySymbol`, `UnicodeCategory.ModifierSymbol` and `UnicodeCategory.OtherSymbol` from the `System.Globalization` namespace.

These are the Unicode characters designed: Sm, Sc, Sk and So, respectively.

All other characters return `False`.

Answer (score 1):

That is not considered a symbol. 
Example:
Char.IsSymbol('^')

returns true.

Char.IsSymbol('%')

returns false.

It is working, just not as you want it to work. You will likely need to define your own function that checks the characters you consider symbols, as well.